# Is it fine to use "this" meaning "super" to use a field

Tags: java, inheritance, this, super

I have a class **A** which extends an abstract class **B**.

Let B have a protected field **value**

I wanna use this field in A. If A doesn't have **value**, I can write `this.value` to get it from B.

Is there any difference with `super.value`?

Comment: Please show code to go along with your description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends ...

If only class `B` declares a field `value` then it doesn't matter. But if class `A` would declare a field `value` too, then it would matter:

Have a look at this example:

```
public class A extends B {

  private Object value = "A";

  public void printValue() {
    System.out.println(super.value);
    System.out.println(this.value);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.printValue();
  }

}
```

If you run this code the output is:

```
B
A
```

The JLS [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)

> The form `super.`*Identifier* refers to the field named *Identifier* of the
>   current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of
>   the superclass of the current class

Thus since the superclass `B` declares a the field `value` it is referred by `super.value`.

Regarding the keyword `this` the JLS [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> ... the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the
>   object for which the instance method or default method was invoked ... The type of `this` is the class or interface type `T` within which the keyword `this`
>   occurs.

In your case the type of `this` is `A`. Thus `this.value` refers to the inherited field `value` declared in class `B`. But if class `A` would declare a field `value`, then `this.value` would refer to the field in class `A`.